What is the name of this C++ syntax: "new (bar[n]) Foo();"?
I have this memory buffer class:
class Buffer {
    const size_t size; // size of one element
    const std::unique_ptr<char[]> data; // storage
public:
    Buffer(const size_t &size, const size_t &max) :
            size(size), data(std::make_unique<char[]>(size * max)) {}
    void *get(const Shared::Index &index) const {
        return data.get() + (size * index);
    }
};

I can have an instance of it to store objects of any type in contiguous memory like:
struct Foo {
    int test;
    Foo(const int &test) :
            test(test) {}
};
const auto buffer = Buffer(sizeof(Foo), 16);

And I seem to be able to create a new instance of Foo at a certain offset in this buffer like:
const auto *foo0 = new (buffer.get(0)) Foo(0);
const auto *foo1 = new (buffer.get(1)) Foo(1);
const auto *foo2 = new (buffer.get(2)) Foo(2);

To my amazement this actually works and I can print the test values like:
std::cout << ((Foo*)buffer.get(0))->test << std::endl;
std::cout << ((Foo*)buffer.get(1))->test << std::endl;
std::cout << ((Foo*)buffer.get(2))->test << std::endl;

And it outputs:
0
1
2

I would like to learn more about what I'm actually doing with new (buffer.get(n)) Foo(n);, but I don't know what this is called and any searches that include "cast" or "new" tend to turn up with basic casting and allocation examples, making it very hard to find the specific feature at work.
How can I look for more information?

VTC as duplicate, but you've clearly done the legwork here -- blame SO's awful search engine for nothing turning up when you were looking around.

No worries, I already got my answer :) I'll let the community handle it from here

Placement new

If placement-args are provided, they are passed to the allocation function as additional arguments. Such allocation functions are known as "placement new", after the standard allocation function void* operator new(std::size_t, void*), which simply returns its second argument unchanged. This is used to construct objects in allocated storage:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Placement_new
Naturally, while typing this question out I go fetch the original article where I got the code in the first place and it just says it right there... It's called a placement new operator. I spent a good day looking for an answer, so in hopes of saving someone else that time I will post the question anyway with this simple self-answer. If you have a better answer to contribute with extra information or context I will accept that one. Thanks for being my rubber duck once again <3

I think you need to add: the need to manually manage the life times of objects created with placement new and the lifetime of the backing storage and show how to delete them.
